# Using two style.bind in Aurelia

Tags: css, aurelia

I'm trying to use two `style.bind` in Aurelia but it's not working.
I could also use just one `style.bind` and apply the styles I want, but I don't know how to do it.

This is the piece of code:

```
<span repeat.for="source of item.data.sources | sort: 'weight' : 'asc'" 
  if.bind="source.weight" 
  class="weight" 
  style.bind="source.weight | fontWeight" 
  style.bind="source.is_italic && 'font-style: italic;'"
>
  ${source.name}
</span>
```

The only thing my `fontWeight` valueConverter does is to return the `font-weight` in CSS syntax:

```
export class FontWeightValueConverter {
  toView(weight) {
    return 'font-weight: ' + weight;
  }
}
```

I have to do it this way because doing

```
style="font-weight: ${ source.weight }"
```

doesn't work... maybe because **weight** is a reserved word?

So, basically, what I want to achieve is to set `font-weight` with my `source.weight` value and then set `font-style: italic;` if the flag `is_italic` is true.

Any ideas?

Comment: `style="font-weight: ${ source.weight }"`, pls read the doc, aurelia cannot do Style Interpolation, style attribute is special. As Jesse answered, aurelia has a css attribute to bypass this limitation. https://aurelia.io/docs/binding/class-and-style#style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `css` attribute for this. You can enter string interpolated styles in the value of the `css` attribute that allows you to create the behavior you need.

In your case, you'd need something like this:

```
<span repeat.for="source of item.data.sources | sort: 'weight' : 'asc'" 
  if.bind="source.weight" 
  class="weight" 
  css="font-weight: ${source.weight}; ${source.is_italic ? 'font-style: italic;' : ''}"
>
  ${source.name}
</span>
```

---

If you wish to read more on style binding, I recommend [this article](https://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/binding-with-style-in-aurelia/).